# Counting number of comparisons in Quick Sort using middle element as Pivot C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm taking a course on Coursera: "Design and Analysis of Algorithms" provided by Stanford University. A text file with 10000 distinct integers is provided in random order. The task is to count the number of comparisons after performing Quick Sort using the middle element as the pivot in each recursive call.

Here is the link to the text file:
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0B_WysIAkKMzzN3o4SEhoS0RjMUU

This is what I did:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int partition(int arr[],int left,int pivot,int right);
int quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right);

int count = 0;

int partition(int arr[],int left,int pivot,int right) {
    int split = left + 1, tmp;

    for (int track = left + 1; track < right; track++) {
        if (arr[track] < pivot) {
            tmp = arr[track];
            arr[track] = arr[split];
            arr[split] = tmp;
            split++;
        }
    }

    tmp = arr[split - 1];
    arr[split - 1] = arr[left];
    arr[left] = tmp;
    return split - 1;
}


int quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right) {

    if (right <= left)
        return 0;

    int mid = (right + left - 1)/2;
    int pivot = arr[mid];
    arr[mid] = arr[left];
    arr[left] = pivot;
    int split = partition(arr,left,pivot,right);
    count += right - left - 1;

    quickSort(arr,left,split);
    quickSort(arr,split + 1,right);
    return count;
}

int main() {

    int ans;
    int arr[10001], i = 0;
    ifstream fin("QuickSort.txt");
    while (fin >> arr[i]) {
        i++;
    }
    fin.close();


    ans = quickSort(arr, 0, i);

    //To check if array is sorted
    for(int x = 0;x < i;x++) {
        cout<<arr[x]<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;

    cout << ans;
    return 0;
}
```

Although the array is sorted fine, the count is 150657, which is wrong.
Can someone point out if I'm missing something here? P.S. I've been at it for days, so I'd really appreciate it if someone helped me out!

Comment: Why are you doing `count += right - left - 1;`?

Comment: I need to count at every recursive call. I assumed the count increases by `M - 1`, where M is the size of the sub-array.

Comment: Are you sure the array is sorted correctly?  Try with different input data.  You seem to be skipping the first element in partitioning, which makes sense in the common quickSort, optimized for random input, which uses the first element as the pivot.  But you are using the middle input position's data for pivot, so skipping the first does not work.

Comment: Yes, I've checked multiple times. I will keep checking with different data sets. If you look closely, before the partition, I exchange the middle element with the first one. `int pivot = arr[mid];
                             arr[mid] = arr[left];
                             arr[left] = pivot;`

Comment: I missed that exch.  So I now believe you that it sorts correctly.  I still don't see how directly counting could give a wrong answer, nor do I see how directly counting could match your original (as you said it did), that seems to me to count too much, nor how directly counting would fail to match my other suggestion.  What is your source of the "correct" number of comparisons?

Comment: OK, I was just wrong about that -2 instead of your -1.  So I see directly counting matches your original.  Now why do you think that is the wrong answer?

Comment: It was checked by the Coursera course. I clicked on a submit button after keying in my answer `(150657)`. It got a zero for that question. And what I inferred from that, was that my answer was wrong.

Comment: I suspected it might be an "official" answer and that the official answer might be wrong.  Minor details of the algorithm, that won't affect the correctness of the sort, will affect the number of comparisons.  I still think you counted your comparisons correctly.  How precisely did they specify details of the sort algorithm?  Maybe they specified (or assumed) some detail different from what you did.

Comment: You're probably right. They said the partition subroutine must be exactly as described in the video lectures. Whats confusing is, I used the same Partition subroutine for Quick Sort with the first element and last element as pivots and got the right answer. I don't really know what I'm missing. But thanks again.

Comment: They specified using the middle element as pivot for this assignment?  Obviously the choice of pivot affects the number of comparisons.  You used the middle element as if you had first swapping it with the first and then used the first as pivot.  That is better than the naive way of using the middle element as pivot.  But it it what the assignment specified?

Comment: Yes, that is how it was explained in the video lectures. I'm aware that there is another way to use middle element as pivot. But that is not what the assignment is asking of me.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to count something, the direct approach is just count what you are counting.  So far as I can tell, you want to count the number of times the following line is executed:

```
if (arr[track] < pivot)
```

So all you need to do is put `++count;` before that line.  If you want to do less computation and/or understand more, think through how many times it is executed:

Edit:  I really wasn't thinking when I wrote the stuff below the ---.  It is just wrong.  So directly counting matches your original method of computing the count.  I tested your code and now believe you are computing the correct count.  Try desk checking a small example, and explain why you believe the giant count is wrong.

I could not access your data file, so I can't confirm or deny your program computes the right count for that file.

---

```
for (int track = left + 1; track < right; track++)
```

That loop would execute its body at most (right-left-2) times.  Since you know right>left at that point, it is safe to say exactly (rather than "at most") right-left-2.

Comment: Counting each time there's a comparison, by putting `++count` before `if (arr[track] < pivot)` still gave me the same answer: `150657`.
I'm required to keep the computation to a minimum and count after each recursive call. I also tried using `count += right - left - 2` which gave me another answer: `140657`, which is again wrong. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

I think your count is computed correctly.  But the global count is so inappropriate, I think that must be corrected.  You could eliminate that variable entirely by changing from:

```
count += right - left - 1;

quickSort(arr,left,split);
quickSort(arr,split + 1,right);
return count;
```

to

```
return
   right - left - 1
+  quickSort(arr,left,split)
+  quickSort(arr,split + 1,right);
```

or make count local, changing to:

```
int count = right - left - 1;

count += quickSort(arr,left,split);
count += quickSort(arr,split + 1,right);
return count;
```

Comment: I tried both of these. I still keep getting the same answer: `150657`. But I really appreciate you trying to help! Thank you. I still haven't found a solution to the problem. I'll keep trying until I do.

Comment: As you mentioned above, there is an "official answer" and `150657` doesn't match that.

Answer (score 0):

```
  count += right - left - 1;
```

I feel that, here instead try using "right - left". Since "right-left+1" is what actually the length of the sub array, this will give the M-1 that you are seeking for. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi,
If you read the above code carefully, `count += right - left - 1;` is what I have used in my quickSort() function.

Answer (score 0):

Your mid index for picking the middle element is not right. You are no accounting for the fact that you are sending in left and right as certain points in the array and not as 0 and n. For example if you have [5,4,2,1,6,7] and you send the right half of this array then your left is gonna be 3 and right is going to be 5 (indices). The median of this array is going to be the 6 but the index of that number is actually 4. What your line here would return is (5 + 3 - 1)/2 = 3 which is not correct. NOTE: I am assuming right is your last element.

```
int mid = (right + left - 1)/2;
```

Try this instead have your array accept left as 0 and right as length of your array instead and for mid try:

```
int mid = ceil((right-left)/2) - 1 + left
```

You can also use your old way of (right + left - 1)/2 but make sure you do a ceil and double check to see if you are actually picking the right medians.

Comment: Sorry I misspoke, you are accounting for your right and left but I think your mid variable is not correct.